# Finding Extremities Points of a Semi Circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

I want to find the coordinates of points $A$ and $B$. The Radius (the red line between $(2,3)$ and $(4,4)$) is known and I need to find what points $A$ and $B$ are by using the existing points and the radius. The distance from $A$ to $(2,3)$ or from $B$ to $(2,3)$ is equal to the radius.

Can anyone help, please!

Comment: Is $\angle A (2,3) B$ a straight angle?

Comment: it's not clear how points $A$ and $B$ are defined. They belong to the circle but what other properties define these points? How are they related to point $(4,4)$?

Comment: This is a SEMI CIRCLE. If you had a circle, 2,3 would be its origin. Cut it in half, (2,3) is still its origin. (2,3) to (4,4) would give the radius of the  Circle. The distance from (2,3) to (4,4) is the same as the distance from (2,3) to A or B.

Comment: Find the line AB equation (vertical to the radios). Find the circle with center given and (4,4). Solve for intersection.